# Horizontal paging a RecyclerView with multiple CardView inside

Tags: android

i'm currently developing an android application: in one of the activities I have multiple CardView programmatically generated inside a RecyclerView. I'd like to have multiple horizontal pages of these in groups of five or six, but I only managed to have a ScrollView with all of the CardView in a vertical list or a single CardView per page.

The Recycler is inside a ScrollView, and I managed to make the second case with

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL, false));

    PagerSnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

thank you for your time

EDIT
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQxff.jpg

This is the layout that I have now, as you can see it's a simple scrollview with multiple cardview inside. What I want to have is to create pages that I can navigate to with horizontal swipes. Each page should have 4 cardview or less

Comment: could you please draw a picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Edited the main post

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to have is to create pages that I can navigate to with
>   horizontal swipes.

I think you can check out [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager).
It does exactly what you want. You can create multiple fragments and put your RecyclerView in each fragments.

Tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide